# Python: Add statements around for-loop body

Tags: python

I have a lot of for-loops like this:

```py
for (i, elem) in enumerate(iter):
    x = do_something1(i, elem)
    do_something2(i, elem)
```

I'd like to wrap each iteration in a bunch of print statements to make it more clear what's happening, e.g.:

```py
for (i, elem) in enumerate(iter):
    print(f"Iteration #{i}")
    print( "-----------")
    x = do_something1(i, elem)
    do_something2(i, elem)
    print("")
```

Note that I don't plan to insert print statements between existing lines of the loop body, only to wrap it around, also I don't plan to use any variables other than `i` in prints.
Question: is there an easy way to do this (maybe `@decorator`-like statement) so as not to copy-paste?

Comment: Side note: you can simplify `(i, elem)` -> `i, elem` and `print("")` -> `print()`

Comment: Are these loops in their own functions?

Comment: Extracting that out into a higher-order function would work. You could also set up logging so it can be easily toggled. This is quite general.

Comment: either make it its own function that just does that (and calls do_something1 and do_something2) or make a decorator.

Comment: @OneCricketeer no, they are in the middle of other code. @Kenny Ostrom I don't quite get what you mean: how do I make a decorator in this case? I thought decorators only work for `def`s and `class`es

Answer (score 0):

```
iter = ("a", "b", "c")
iter2 = ("x", "y", "z", "t")

def do_something1(i, elem):
    print("do something 1")
    return 15

def do_something2(i, elem):
    print("do something 2")

def wrapForLoop(doFor):
    def wrapper(iter):
        for (i, elem) in enumerate(iter):
            print(f"Iteration #{i} - Elem #{elem}")
            print("----------")
            x = do_something1(i, elem)
            do_something2(i, elem)
            print("")
    return wrapper

@wrapForLoop
def doFor(iter):
    pass

doFor(iter)
doFor(iter2)
```

Comment: It seems this will only work if all loops have the same body, so that it can be extracted to a function (`wrapper`)? In such a case there's no need for decorators

Comment: My English not good, I try to understand you, and i think you want decorator for do this :) 
You can use `doFor(iter, withInfo)` and  `wrapper(item, withInfo):
   if withInfo:
       for with info
else:
for withoutInfo
`

Comment: I want to add print statements around loop body, but change code as little as possible :) So not to use new functions.